# Spell:insert is not setting or inheriting permisions

Tags: marklogic

I'm using `Spell:insert` to keep a dictionary in a database. Once I've saved it, I check to see the permissions on the document and they are blank. The parent directory has permissions but the document that was inserted by the `Spell:insert` doesn't have any permissions on it.

Is there something I'm missing?

Does the `Spell:insert` not set permissions and I should call `xdmp:document-set-permissions` on the URI once its been saved? If that is the case why would I use `Spell:insert` over `xdmp:document-insert`?

Here is the xquery code I'm using to insert the dictionary into the database

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace spell = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell" at "/MarkLogic/spell.xqy";


let $words := fn:distinct-values(cts:words(("a"),("document","score-zero","collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/en") , cts:directory-query("/documents/", "infinity")))
let $dictionary := 
  <dictionary xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell">
  { 
    for $word in $words 
    where xdmp:castable-as("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell", "word-type", $word)
    return 
    try {
         <word>{ $word }</word> 
       }
    catch ($exception) {
      ()
    }

  }
  </dictionary>

let $insert := spell:insert("/configuration/search/word-in-documents.xml", $dictionary)
return $dictionary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spell:insert` is just this:

```
declare function 
insert($uri as xs:string,
       $dict as element(spell:dictionary))
as empty-sequence()
{
  xdmp:document-insert($uri, validate as spell:dictionary {$dict},
    xdmp:default-permissions(), ("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/documents",
          "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/spell"))
};
```

If you want documents to have particular permissions, set the default permissions of the role you're using: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/permissions